# How in Mongo to add or set the updatedAt field manually

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I built in my NodeJS Mongo API a method to patch update the fields of one project but I'm unable to update the updatedAt field to the `new Date()`. When I update I should also be able to update the Date of the updatedAt field but I have issues to do so.

What I tried is this method:

```
async update(req, res) {
        try {
            // Check for empty req.body
            if (Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
                throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(500, "Nothing to update");
            }

            // Req.body
            const updateProject = req.body;

            // Set empty OBJ
            const set = {};

            // Loop the fields to update
            for (const field in updateProject) {
                set["project.$." + field] = updateProject[field];
            }

            // Update the project on that username
            const projectToUpdate = await Student.updateOne(
                {
                    username: res.username.username,
                    "project._id": req.params.projectId
                },
                { $set: set },
                {
                    $push: {
                        updatedAt: new Date() // Don't know how to update this ??
                    }
                }
            );

            // Check and send
            if (projectToUpdate)
                res.json({ Message: "Updated", projectUpdated: req.body });
            else throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(500, "Nothing to update");
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
        }
    }
```

Also, I would like to know the way I'm writing this is right or if there will be a better way to so for a patch

Schema

```
const { Connect } = require("../db");
const { isEmail, isURL, toDate } = require("validator");

const projectSchema = {
    name: {
        type: String,
        minlength: [4, "Name need to be longer then 4 characters"],
        maxlength: [15, "Name cannot exceed 15 characters"],
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        sparse: true
    },

    description: {
        type: String,
        minlength: [25, "Description need to be longer then 25 characters"],
        maxlength: [125, "Description cannot exceed 125 characters"],
        required: true
    },

    linkRepo: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        validate: {
            validator: string => isURL(string),
            message: "URL is not valid"
        }
    },

    linkLive: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        validate: {
            validator: string => isURL(string),
            message: "URL is not valid"
        }
    },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    required: false
},

updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    required: false
}
};

const studentSchema = {
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, "Email is required"],
        validate: {
            validator: string => isEmail(string),
            message: "Provided email is invalid"
        }
    },

    dateOfBirth: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: string => toDate(string),
            message: "DoB invalid"
        }
    },

    project: [projectSchema],

    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: false
    },

    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: false
    }
};

const studentSchemaModel = Connect.Schema(studentSchema);
const Student = Connect.model(collectionName, studentSchemaModel);

module.exports = Student;
```

Comment: will it be  `username: res.username.username`, or   `username: req.username.username`,

Comment: that works perfectly as it is my question was about the updatedAt as I would like to know how to update it

Comment: as your query seems wrong so, because `res.username.username` will be undefind as not mentioned on above

Comment: It is not undefined becasue that comes from another middleware and I tested I'm able to update all but not the updatedAt which is my question in place. 
I can show you the middleware I built for it which checks the username before and send it forward. So I can update all the body fields but I don't know how to update the Date

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with `$push` ,I hope `updatedAt` is not array if you want to do you can do under `$set`, better approach i would like to suggest is

If you are using mongoose you can set timeStamp for this, you don't need to worry about update date manually, `timestamps` will take care of that, whenever your document will get updated.

If set `timestamps`, `mongoose` assigns `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields to your schema, the type assigned is Date.

By default, the name of two fields are `createdAt` and `updatedAt`, customize the field name by setting `timestamps.createdAt` and `timestamps.updatedAt`.

For more info:- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        sFirstName: String,
        sLastName: String,
        eUserType: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['user', 'admin'],
            default: 'user',
        },
        eStatus: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['y', 'n', 'd'],
            default: 'y',
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: { createdAt: 'dCreatedDate', updatedAt: 'dUpdatedDate' },
    }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', User);
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail as this above gives errors
TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `DCreatedDate` is not a valid type at path `timestamps.createdAt`
Do I have to pass on createdAt/updatedAt the new Date() or what?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but suggesting OP to use mongoose instead of fixing the actual error in the code isn't a very good answer in my opinion. See @Sarfraaz's answer.

Comment: I tried the answer from @ @Sarfraaz's but still not working the updatedAt is not been updated

Comment: can you give try to above solution as well, @AntoineBolvy thanks for now i have updated my answer with both

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with `$push` , if you want to update the value, you can do it using `$set` itself

So in your current code, you can initialize `set` with `updatedAt` value as `new Date()` & it will update the `updatedAt` as you wish to

```
async update(req, res) {
    try {
        // Check for empty req.body
        if (Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
            throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(500, "Nothing to update");
        }

        // Req.body
        const updateProject = req.body;

        // Set empty OBJ
        const set = {'updatedAt': new Date()};

        // Loop the fields to update
        for (const field in updateProject) {
            set["project.$." + field] = updateProject[field];
        }

        // Update the project on that username
        const projectToUpdate = await Student.updateOne(
            {
                username: res.username.username,
                "project._id": req.params.projectId
            },
            { $set: set },
          {new:true}
        );

        // Check and send
        if (projectToUpdate)
            res.json({ Message: "Updated", projectUpdated: projectToUpdate });
        else throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(500, "Nothing to update");
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it ;)

Comment: I tried but is not working the updatedAt do not update still :(

Comment: Please share your schema, that'd be helpful

Comment: I added please check

Comment: Is it throwing error or posting wrong data in res.json?

Comment: No errors at all not wrong data just the updatedAt missing to be updated to new Date

Comment: do `console.log(set)` before firing the query & see if you get the update Object correctly there, also, try my updated answer

Comment: I tried this `set["project.$.updatedAt"] = Date.now();` after the for loop and worked actually

Comment: Looks like you wanted to update that inside `project` sub document & not the main document

Comment: Yes that was my issue

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question as I found one solution which worked for me but maybe there are better options.

I added after the for loop this:
`set["project.$.updatedAt"] = Date.now();`

Like:

```
try {
            // Check for empty req.body
            if (Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
                throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(500, "Nothing to update");
            }

            // Req.body
            const updateProject = req.body;

            // Set empty OBJ
            const set = {};

            // Loop the fields to update
            for (const field in updateProject) {
                set["project.$." + field] = updateProject[field];
            }

            set["project.$.updatedAt"] = Date.now(); //=> I added this

            // Update the project on that username
            const projectToUpdate = await Student.updateOne(
                {
                    username: res.username.username,
                    "project._id": req.params.projectId
                },
                { $set: set }
            );

            // Check and send
            if (projectToUpdate)
                res.json({ Message: "Updated", projectUpdated: req.body });
            else throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(500, "Nothing to update");
```

In this way is updating the updateAt